# How do I combine my shortcodes?

Tags: shortcode

Example I want combine shortcode for first paragraph and dropcap.

```
function st_dropcap( $atts, $content = null ) {
    return '<span class="dropcap">'.$content.'</span>';
}
add_shortcode('dropcap', 'st_dropcap');

function st_paragraph( $atts, $content = null ) {
    return '<p class="first-paragraph">'.$content.'</p>';
}
add_shortcode('paragraph', 'st_paragraph');
```

On post I tried something like this

```
[paragraph][dropcap]W[/dropcap]elcome to my blog[/paragraph]
```

Only paragraph is working. How do I combine this code?

Let me know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `st_paragraph()` to this:

```
function st_paragraph( $atts, $content = null ) {
    return '<p class="first-paragraph">'.do_shortcode($content).'</p>';
}
```

See [Codex documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Enclosing_vs_self-closing_shortcodes).